# What is WordPress doing for content encoding in its MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, perl, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

For some convoluted reasons best left behind us, I require direct access the contents of a [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) database.  I'm using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) 5.0.70-r1 on [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) with WordPress 2.6, and Perl 5.8.8 ftr.

So, sometimes we get high-order characters in the blog, we have quite a few authors contributing too, for the most part these characters end up in WordPress's database in `wp_posts.post_content` or `wp_postmeta.meta_value`, Wordpress is displaying these correctly on its site, but the database stores it using single byte encoding that I can't figure out how to convert to the correct string.  Today's example:

The blog shows this, and doesn't even seem to escape any chars in the HTML,

```
   Hãhãhães
```

but the database, when viewed via the MySQL prompt, has,

```
   HÃ£hÃ£hÃ£es
```

So clearly this is some kind of double-byte encoding issue, but I don't know how I can correct it.  I need to be able to pull that second string from the database (because that's what it gives me) and convert it to the first one, and I need to do so using Perl.

Also, just to help unmuddy any waters, I took these strings and printed out the ASCII codes for each character using Perl's `ord()` function.

Here is the output of the "wrong" string:

```
H = 72
Ã = 195
£ = 163
h = 104
Ã = 195
£ = 163
h = 104
Ã = 195
£ = 163
e = 101
s = 115
```

This is the correct string, that I need to produce in my script:

```
H = 72
ã = 227
h = 104
ã = 227
h = 104
ã = 227
e = 101
s = 115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it...  Thanks to those who read and/or tried.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('mysql:etc:etc');
$dbh->{mysql_enable_utf8}++;  #<---- solution
```

That's all, sigh...

Not sure about the MySQL prompt thing, because I don't really care, but I'm sure it's a similar solution, to make sure MySQL is returning results in double-bytes to its prompt.  Though see my comment above, "set character_set_*" variables didn't seem to affect it though.

Answer (score 1):

How about `SET NAMES 'utf8'`?

Comment: "SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server"
//
mmm.. i'm not sending sql to the server... my problem is in the data the server is returning, and how to reencode it
//
also, from the mysql docs on set names, i found character_set_results, character_set_client, though SETting these to 'utf8' doesn't seem to affect the select query to produce the badly encoded string above. I also tried merely "charset utf8;" which also seemed to have no effect

Comment: Could it be issue with your terminal? (Assuming you are using one.)

Comment: no the terminal is not the problem, that's a red herring.  the issue is that i don't know how to convert this single-byte encoded string with the correct double-byte encoded string

Comment: Corrected the syntax `UTF-8 → 'utf8'`. This maybe gives you some ideas: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8/mysql